# dygraphs configuring dual x axes

Tags: plot, dygraphs

I have a dygraph that is plotting two sets of data. The one x-axis is 1 to 600 and the second y-axis is 1-300. How can both be plotted showing the x-axis and the 300 point plot scaled correctly. See the attached example of what I am getting. Would love to have numbers on the second y axis too.
thanks[Current Code Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUjrv.jpg)

Comment: please paste the code instead of screenshot